# How do we know that Fermat wrote his famous note in 1637?

Tags: ho.history-overview, nt.number-theory

It is widely stated that Fermat wrote his famous note on sums of powers ("Fermat's last theorem") in, or around, 1637. How do we know the date, if the note was only discovered after his death, in 1665?

My interest in this stems from the fact that if this is true, we can be absolutely certain that whatever proof Fermat in mind was wrong, and he must have noticed (or he would have mentioned it to his correspondents in later years). On the other hand, if the note had been written much later the reasoning would fail. I have used this argument previously in talks for the general public, rather acritically, and I would like to make sure it is sound.

Comment: 1637 is prime and the next primes 1657 and 1663 (less than 1665) are too far from the dates he was working on the subject. :-)

Comment: There might be something of interest in Weil's historical book on number theory, from Hammurapi to Legendre....

Comment:   I think most number theorists-in light of the sheer ophistication of the methods used in solving the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture and Ribet's proof of the epsilon conjecture (both of which are necessary to prove the general Fermat theorum,from my nderstanding)-that Fermat *couldn't* have had a valid proof.He *could* have had a proof of a special case,several of which were already possible with the machinery available at the time-Fermat himself apparently proved in unpublished notes the case where n=4 by infinite descent. 

Comment: 
(continued)The magic of Fermat's last theorum-and why it's fascinated so many for over 3 centuries-is the remote possibility that he might have stumbled onto an actual proof using methods no one's ever thought of.Namely,that a 17th century mind would have been capable of what "more advanced" minds where incapable of for so long. It's also that a theorum so incredibly simple to state turned out to have a proof that required the development of entire regions of the structure of modern mathematics, such as elliptic curves and algebraic number theory.    

Comment: before/in case anyone downvotes this -- this seems more like a comment than an "answer". – Yemon Choi 8 mins ago @Yemon As you can see,I've deleted the post and added it to the  first set of comments.Hope that preempts any new problems.

Comment: Andrew, I hope you won't be too offended if I remark that your answer/comments is, at best, tangential to the present question: 

$$\text{How do we date Fermat's famous note?}$$

Comment: @Victor Sigh,Can't win.

Comment: @Andrew L : Is Victor's comment really that unfair?

Comment: @Andrew, I really wish you would stop treating everyone as an enemy.  Victor is pointing out that you have not addressed the actual question being asked.  This is not a personal attack against you.

Comment: @Andrew L : I want to expand my comment in the hope that it will help you.  What you posted is "wikipedia level knowledge".  There are times when such general comments are helpful, especially if the post is obviously the work of a beginner.  However, the current post is not asking for background and asks a very technical question : how do we know the date of Fermat's undated marginal note?  The author of the question demonstrates enough knowledge that it is clearly unnecessary (and maybe a little insulting) to post background knowledge that most people who understand the question would know.

Comment: @Andrew L - the word you are looking for is "theorem". 

Comment: @Gerry Thank you for the spelling lesson. @Qiaochu I'm not,you're understandably overreacting given my history.I don't think Victor is even wrong. I'm just a little frustrated,is all. @Andy Calm down,take a deep breath.You made your point. I'm surprised foresic historians haven't made an empirical attempt to actually date the note,if it still exists.I'm certain laboratory methods exist that can accurately date it.The problem of course is whether or not a method exists that can date it without destroying it.  

Comment: I'd like frankly to get John Stillwell's input at this thread-he's one of our resident experts at historical issues.

Comment: @Wadim I really hope you're not serious. How is my opinion of my teacher offensive?!? Seriously,I do not understand this place sometimes! I'm removing the comment to be safe.I can't believe this.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for removing the comment; I followed you. But I am definitely serious: it's better to estimate theorems rather than people.

Comment: Wow. You guys should really lighten up.

Comment: For what it is worth, in view of the fact that Andrew L was recently suspended and that he is feeling cornered and isolated, it would have been better to leave him alone for a while. Now he seems to have left for good. Might I suggest that people overreacted with this double suspension and all? http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/554/i-dont-appreciate-being-made-the-dancing-bear-in-this-forum/ 

Comment: @Angelo. Welcome to Mathoverflow.

Comment: (In the interest of full disclosure):-  I was also part of the people who recently found fault with Andrew L; but my intention was merely to improve his typography. 

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Not only do we not know the date, we don't even know whether he wrote the remark at all.
For all we know it might have been invented by his son Samuel, who published his father's comments.

In his letters, Fermat never mentioned the general case at all, but quite often posed the problem of solving the cases $n=3$ and $n=4$. I am almost certain that Fermat discovered infinite descent around 1640, which means that in 1637 he did not have any chance of proving FLT for exponent 4 (let alone in general).

In 1637, Fermat also stated the polygonal number theorem and claimed to have a proof; this is just about as unlikely as in the case of FLT -- I guess Fermat wasn't really careful in these early days.

Let me also mention that Fermat posed FLT for $n=3$ always as a problem or as a question, and did not claim unambiguously to have a proof; my interpretation is that he did not have a proof for $n = 3$, and that he knew he did not have one.

**Edit** Let me briefly quote two letters from Fermat:

I. [Oeuvres](http://wlym.com/~animations/fermat/) II, 202--205, letter to Roberval Aug. 1640 Fermat claims that if $p = 4n-1$ be prime, then $p$ does not divide a sum of two squares $x^2 + y^2$ with $\gcd(x,y) = 1$. Then he writes

*I have to admit frankly that I have found nothing in number theory 
that has pleased me as much as the demonstration of this proposition, 
and I would be very pleased if you made the effort of finding it, if 
only for learning whether I estimate my invention more highly than it 
deserves.*

This looks as if Fermat had just discovered "his method" of descent.
Starting from $x^2 + y^2 = pr$ one has to show that there is a prime
$q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ dividing $r$ which is strictly less than $p$.

II. In his letter to Carcavi from Aug. 1659 (Oeuvres II, 431--436), Fermat writes:

*I then considered certain questions which, although negative, do 
not remain to receive a very great difficulty, for it will be easily 
seen that the method of applying descent is completely different from 
the preceding [questions]. Such cases include the following:*

1. There is no cube that can be divided into two cubes.
2. There is only one square number which, augmented by $2$,
     makes a cube, namely $25$.
3. There are only two square numbers which, augmented by $4$, 
     make a cube, namely $4$ and $121$.
4. All squared powers of $2$ augmented by $1$ are prime numbers.

My interpretation of this is that Fermat lists four results which he
believes can be proved using his method of descent. In my opinion 
this implies that Fermat did not have a proof of FLT for exponent $3$ 
in 1659.

**Edit 2**
In light of the discission at [wiki.fr](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:D%C3%A9monstrations_du_dernier_th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Fermat) let
me add a couple of additional remarks along with a promise that a nonelectronic
publication of my views on Fermat will appear within the next two years (if I can
find a publisher, that is).

A search in google books for "hanc marginis" and Fermat for the
years up to 1900 reveals several hits, none of which claims that 
the remark was written around 1637; in particular there are no dates
given in Fermat's Oeuvres or in Heath's Diophantus. Starting with 
Dickson's history, this changes dramatically, and nowadays the date 
1637 seems to be firmly attached to this entry.

The dating of the entry seems to come from a letter written by
Fermat to J. de Sainte-Croix via Mersenne mentioned in Nurdin's 
answer; this letter is not dated, but since Descartes, in a letter 
to Mersenne from 1638, refers to  a result he credits to Sainte-Croix, 
but which Fermat claims he has discovered, it is believed that Fermat's 
letter to Mersenne was written well before that date. The reasons for 
dating it to September 1636 are not explained in Fermat's Oeuvres.

In this letter, Fermat poses the problem of finding two fourth
powers whose sum is a fourth power, and of finding two cubes whose
sum is a cube. The reasoning seems to be that in 1636, Fermat
had not yet found (or believed to have found) a proof of the general 
theorem, so the entry must have been written at a later date. 
Since he did not refer to the general theorem in any of his 
existant letters, it is also believed that he soon found his 
mistake, so the entry cannot have been written at a time when
Fermat was mature enough to find sufficiently difficult proofs.

Let me also add that the following dates can be deduced from 
Fermat's letters:

- 1638  Numbers 4n-1 are not sums of two rational squares
- 1640  Fermat's Little Theorem
- 1640  Discovery of infinite descent; used for showing that 
      (1) primes 4n-1 do not divide sums of to squares.
- 1640  Statement of the Two-Squares Theorem
- 1641 - 1645  Proof of (2) FLT for exponent 4
- later: Proof of  (3) the Two-Squares Theorem

It is impossible to attach any dates between 1644 and 1654 to
Fermat's discoveries since he either wrote hardly any letter
in this period, or all of them are lost.

Fermat claimed to have discovered infinite descent in connection
with results such as (1), and that he at first could apply it
only to negative statements such as (2), whereas it took him a 
long time until he could use his method for proving positive 
statements such as (3). Thus the proofs of (1) - (2) - (3) were
found in this order.

This means in particular that if Fermat's entry in his Diophantus
was written around 1637, then the marvellous proof must have been
a proof that does not use infinite descent.

I would also like to remark that the Fermat equation for exponents
3 and 4 had already been studied by Arab mathematicians, such as 
Al-Khujandi and Al-Khazin, who both attempted proving that there
are no solutions. The cubic equation also shows up in problems
posed by Frenicle and van Schooten in response to Fermat's
challenge to the English mathematicians.

Comment: +1 for addressing the original question. (This is not meant sarcastically.)

Comment: Infinite descent wasn't discovered in 1640. It was used by ancient Greeks to prove the irrationality of sqrt(2)

Comment: Still, Fermat discovered it around 1640. It was also used in Euclid's proof that every number has a prime divisor, and Fermat knew the Elements inside out. And the proof of the irrationality of sqrt(2) can be given the form of infinite descent, but the one added as Prop. 117 to Euclid's book X is the proof via contradiction starting from p^2 = 2q^2 with coprime numbers p and q. The geometric version of the descent proof cannot be found in Greek sources, to the best of my knowledge. 

Comment: Nice answer but just one small quibble: "those early days" is not quite accurate. Fermat's mathematical activity goes back to at least 1629 when he worked out a preliminary version of his adequality technique while working in Bordeaux. One could perhaps even say that 1637 is already toward the end of his productive period in mathematics. He devoted most of his energies to law and to the parliament in Toulouse (which was the judicial, legislative, and executive branches rolled into one).

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Were you able to find a publisher for your views on Fermat?

Comment: I'll say a few things about Fermat in my history of number theory (in German for the time being) due in late 2019 or early 2020..

Answer (score 23):

There is a letter from Fermat to Mersenne, sent in September 1636, where Fermat proposes such problem:

> $3^o$. Invenire duo quadratoquadratos quorum summa aequetur
>   quadratoquadrato, aut duos cubos
>   quorum summa sit cubus.

or "Find two fourth powers, whose sum is the fourth power or two cubes, whose sum is a cube."

So, Fermat definitely had thought about this problem in 1636. The letter could be found [here](http://www.archive.org/details/oeuvresdefermat942ferm).

There are also other letters, where he mentions these problems(for example letter to Mersenne from may of 1640), but they were written later.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the exponent 4 case, but my question is about the general case. Does Fermat mention this in the other letters to Mersenne?

Comment: Hm, David A. Cox states in "Introduction to Fermat's last theorem"(http://math.stanford.edu/~lekheng/flt/cox.pdf) that Fermat stated FLT for exponents n=3,4.

Comment: The date of note as 1637 appears in Dickson's "History of the Theory of Numbers", but he only gives reference to the 1670's pulication of "Arithmetica" with Fermat's notes.

Answer (score 14):

Below is Andre Weil's opinion on this general topic, from his historical treatise *Number Theory*, p.104.

> As we have observed in Chap. I, S.X,
>   the most significant  problems in
>   Diophantus are concerned with curves
>   of genus  0 or 1. With Fermat this
>   turns into an almost exclusive 
>   concentration on such curves. Only on
>   one ill-fated occasion  did Fermat
>   ever mention a curve of higher genus,
>   and there  can hardly remain any doubt
>   that this was due to some 
>   misapprehension on his part, even
>   though, by a curious  twist of fate,
>   his reputation in the eyes of the
>   ignorant came  to rest chiefly upon
>   it. By this we refer of course to the 
>   incautious words "et generaliter
>   nullam in infinitum potestatem"  in
>   his statement of "Fermat's last
>   theorem" as it came to be  vulgarly
>   called: "No cube can be split into two
>   cubes, nor  any biquadrate into two
>   biquadrates, nor generally any power 
>   beyond the second into two of the same
>   kind" is what he wrote  into the
>   margin of an early section of his
>   Diophantus  (Fe.I.291, Obs.II), adding
>   that he had discovered a truly 
>   remarkable proof for this "which this
>   margin is too narrow  to hold". How
>   could he have guessed that he was
>   writing  for eternity? We know his
>   proof for biquadrates (cf. above, 
>   S.X); he may well have constructed a
>   proof for cubes, similar  to the one
>   which Euler discovered in 1753 (cf.
>   infra, S.XVI);  he frequently repeated
>   those two statements (e.g. 
>   Fe.II.65,376,433), but never the more
>   general one. For a  brief moment
>   perhaps, and perhaps in his younger
>   days  (cf. above, S.III), he must have
>   deluded himself into thinking  that he
>   had the principle of a general proof;
>   what he had  in mind on that day can
>   never be known.

Answer (score 8):

I share the idea that the famous remark might have been invented by C-S Fermat in editing Diophantus volume in 1670. The reasons for this are the following.

1. Actually, the original volume of Diophantus was never presented to public, unlike some other books owned by PF. One has to believe C-S and only him that the remark actually existed.
2. If we read the whole volume, as it was printed, we can see that some of PF's remarks are considerably longer than the famous one. The latter is 4 lines long, while some others are 3 pages long, filled with not that essential calculations. The natural question, why the lack of space suddenly manifested itself in the famous remarks but were absent in many others, leads to the assumption that it is not the lack of space that was the reason for such an incomplete note, but simply the inability of the Author to write more.
3. C-S was not a mathematician, however he was involved in some activities related with mathematics. He surely had some common interest with PF. This statement is proved by the letter from P.Huet, addressed to both.
4. Let us look at some other books belonging to PF, the ones that survived. One can see that the remarks are written by PF in a very 'shorthand', with a lot of abbreviations, often unintelligible. For publishing, one needed to decipher the abbreviations. Who did this. In the introduction to the edition, C-S does not thank anyone for help in this deciphering. So, he, probably, did it by himself. And not always correctly.

Answer (score 5):

There is a relevant piece of information that does not seem to have been mentioned in the other answers so here it is.

Fermat became acquainted with the book by Diophantus by studying in the library of d'Espagnet (father Jean and son Etienne) in Bordeaux around 1629.  This was a period of great creative activity for Fermat, including the invention of the method of [adequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequality) (incidentally the term derives from Bachet's latin term adaequalitat which itself derives from Diophantus's Greek parisotes).

So Fermat may well have written the comment in the  margin of the book *Arithmetic* by Diophantus as early as 1629.