# Is there any solution to the diophantine  equation $1/x^m+1/y^n=1/z^t$ in which x, y, z are not coprime

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $x,y,z$ are coprime, this equation has not any solution with an elementary method. I want to know a solution of this equation when $x,y,z$ are not coprime.

Comment: $$\frac1{2^{1638}}+\frac1{2^{1638}}=\frac1{2^{1637}}$$

Comment: @wadim thank you for example, buti need complate solution

Comment: I need an explanation: Why 1638? Isn't $\frac{1}{2^{42}}+\frac{1}{2^{42}}=\frac{1}{2^{41}}$ more canonical?

Comment: What do you mean by a complete solution? All solutions or exhibit a solution for each $m,n,p$? (where $m,n,p$ are pairwise coprime let's say, so that we don't involve FLT)?

Comment: if x,y,z are coprime this equation has not any solution,if x,y,z are not coprime so i ask about all solutions and also m,n,p are coprime

Comment: I think the place to start is ${1\over a}+{1\over b}={1\over c}$ for which an elementary argument will disclose all solutions, then see when $a$, $b$, and $c$ can be powers (I take it you are really only interested in cases where the exponents exceed 1). 

Comment: @Helge, that a hint: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33265/ . But your solution is worth canonisation as well. :-)$$\ $$ @Hashem, yes I have the feeling that you wish more. ;-)

Comment: Wadim, Helge is correct. The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. In the first novel and radio series, a group of hyper-intelligent pan-dimensional beings demand to learn the Ultimate Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything from the supercomputer, Deep Thought, specially built for this purpose. It takes Deep Thought 7½ million years to compute and check the answer, which turns out to be 42. 

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to construct a solution for each triple $(m,n,t)$ of pairwise coprime integers.

Start by choosing your favorite $a,b,c$ so that $a+b=c$ and write down the prime factorizations $$a=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i} \ , \ b=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\beta_i} \ , \ c=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\gamma_i}.$$ Now, by the Chinese remainder theorem find large enough $\delta_i$'s so that $$\alpha_i-\delta_i\equiv 0\pmod{m}$$
$$\beta_i-\delta_i\equiv 0\pmod{n}$$
$$\gamma_i-\delta_i\equiv 0\pmod{t}$$ and denote $D=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\delta_i}$. You have $$\frac{a}{D}+\frac{b}{D}=\frac{c}{D}$$ and so $x^{-m}+y^{-n}=z^{-t}$ for some integers $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to construct a solution for each triple $(m,n,t)$ of pairwise coprime integers. Find $u$ and $v$ such that $mnu-tv=1$ (so all that's really necessary is that $t$ be relatively prime to $mn$). Then $${1\over(2^{nu})^m}+{1\over(2^{mu})^n}={1\over(2^v)^t}$$

Comment: that's what you get from my construction above, if you start with $1+1=2$ :)

Comment: True. I guess instead of calling it "another way" I should have called it the simplest instance of your way. 